# Как сделать такой listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gui, design

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой `listbox` на wpf+mvvm?  Как вертикальную линию я знаю как сделать, а вот с остальным вообще нет идей, так ладно сделать кастомный контейнер, мне вот интересно как организовать бизнес модель (грубо говоря за бизнес модель служить у нас будет `list` из классов структурой `msg[Integer idmsg, String text, Date prishlo, Integer idUser]`) :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### UPD #1 :

Ну вот, такой у меня ItemTemplate :

```
    <ListBox Name="chat" Margin="248,212,43,40">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="20,10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Height="85" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="184">
                        <Label Content="Alex-rudenkiy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label Content="22:08" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) — это набор инструментов для построения пользовательских интерфейсов, " VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF727FFD" Height="380" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="3" Margin="432,212,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Comment: Ну VM у вас правильная. UI будет немного сложный, но ничего космического вроде.

Comment: @VladD ну вот, смотрите какую я структуру набросал...

Comment: Ну где-то так. Я пришлю свой вариант, когда доберусь домой.

Comment: @VladD ой, огромное спасибо ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получился такой вариант.

VM-классы:

```
class MessageVM : VM
{
    public MessageVM(string text, DateTime postedAt, UserVM author)
    {
        Text = text; PostedAt = postedAt; Author = author;
    }
    public string Text { get; }
    public DateTime PostedAt { get; }
    public UserVM Author { get; }
}

class UserVM : VM
{
    public UserVM(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/> <!-- автор и дата-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>  <!-- вертикальная линия -->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>   <!-- текст -->
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Author.Name}"
                               TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding PostedAt, StringFormat=d}"
                               TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <!-- верхняя часть ровно 5 px, средняя от 5 до 40, 
                         нижняя как минимум 15, растягивается сначала средняя -->
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100000000*" MinHeight="5" MaxHeight="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="15"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- вертикальная линия через все три части -->
                    <Path Data="M0,0 L0,1" Stroke="Violet" StrokeThickness="4"
                          Stretch="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          StrokeStartLineCap="Square" StrokeEndLineCap="Square"/>
                    <!-- растягивающийся круг -->
                    <Path Stroke="Violet" StrokeThickness="4" Stretch="Uniform"
                          Grid.Row="1" Fill="Violet">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Кроме того, чтобы форматирование даты соответствовало текущему языку, вам нужно в конструкторе `App` использовать [следующее заклинание](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520115/276994):

```
public App()
{
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
          typeof(FrameworkElement),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
              XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

Результат:

[image: почему именно фиолетовый?]

Нижний круг меньше, чтобы 15 пикселей нижней части линии смогли влезть.